# Laravel API URI issue

Tags: api, laravel-4

I installed the Laravel to Linux box and MacOS box using different installation methods.

In the linux box. routes shows like below.

[image]

So, if I want to access the comments API, I can use URI as "localhost/api/comments"

In case of MacOX box, the route shows like below. I see there is difference in the URI that "|HEAD" is added in the URI.

So if I want to access the comments API, I can't use the URI like Linux Box. I have to use URI like "localhost/index.php/api/comments". I have to put the "index.php" into the URI to access all APIs. It is really confuse and inconvenient. It seems a configuration in Laravel makes this different. How I can remove the "index.php" in the URI? 
Thank you for your help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache on OS X? In your vHost you should have something like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/laravel">
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>
```

You can use the PHP built-in web server by typing `$ php artisan serve` in your terminal at the root of your Laravel project (not in your public directory) and then navigate to `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Apache on OS X and changed the default url from /Library/WebServer/Documents/ to /Library/WebServer/Documents/laravel/public. The <Directory> tag includes "AllowOverride None". I want to use Apache on OS X instead of PHP built-in web server.